# How to install localdb separately?

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

If I have to work with `localdb`, do we need to install it separately?

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio installed, SQL Server 2012 installed, .net 4.0.2 update installed. But I don't see localdb in the PC yet.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh510202.aspx)

> The primary method of installing LocalDB is by using the
>   SqlLocalDB.msi program. LocalDB is an option when installing any SKU
>   of SQL Server 2012 Express. **Select LocalDB on the Feature Selection
>   page during installation of SQL Server Express**. There can be only one
>   installation of the LocalDB binary files for each major SQL Server
>   Database Engine version. Multiple Database Engine processes can be
>   started and will all use the same binaries. An instance of the SQL
>   Server Database Engine started as the LocalDB has the same limitations
>   as SQL Server Express

[image]

Or you can download standalone **SqlLocalDB.msi** from the list of available downloads on the `SQL Express` downloading [page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

[image]

To locate `localdb` instance on your PC simply try to connect to `(localdb)\Projects`

[image]

Comment: Hoping to save some others time... SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB Service Pack 2 (v11.0) is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=43351

Comment: @VahidN it looks like with SQL Express 2016 you can't download just LocalDB. The download link doesn't give you the multi-select modal like previous versions do.

Comment: direct download link of en_sql_server_2016_localdb_x64_8762243: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/2/E12B3655-D817-49BA-B934-CEB9DAC0BAF3/SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: @VahidN do I need to install that if I have SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition installed? How do I check if I already have LocalDb installed? The above `(localdb)\Projects` didn't work for me!

Comment: Open a new topic + Run `SqlLocalDB info` command to find the installed instances.

Comment: LocalDB 2017: https://download.microsoft.com/download/E/F/2/EF23C21D-7860-4F05-88CE-39AA114B014B/SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: SQL Server 2019 LocalDB: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SqlLocalDB.msi

Comment: SQL Server 2022 LocalDB: https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/d/38de7036-2433-4207-8eae-06e247e17b25/SqlLocalDB.msi

Answer (score 24):

If you downloaded **SqlLocalDB.msi** You can use silent install.

```
msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES
```

Remember about administrative rights for installation !

Answer (score 21):

Note for people who got SQL 2016. You do in fact need to choose "Express" during installation of SQL 2016 to choose "localDB" option. If you choose anything else (like Developer edition for example), "localDB" will not appear as option under "Shared features"

**Developer Edition**
[image]

**SQL Express**
[image]

Comment: So are you saying you can install SQL Server 2016 and then afterwards install LocalDB as part of SQL Server Express 2016?

Comment: I'd like to know this too! How do I get LocalDB when I have SQL Server 2016 Developer edition installed?

Comment: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799012 There's a downloader that's about 3 MB. That allows for downloading SQL Server Express (1.4 GB) or LocalDb (44 MB)

Answer (score 12):

Question is old but I think this is allways nice to know:

How to check if you have LocalDB installed, and if you do have it, which version it is:

1. Open Command Prompt
2. Enter "SqlLocalDB info"
   (without quotes)
3. Hit 'Enter' and your should see something like 
   [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afs2y.png),

which means you have version "MSSQLLocalDB" installed.

There are a couple of versions:

- v11.0
- v12.0
- v13.0
  and
- MSSQLLocalDB

Comment: I might add that if you wanted to open this database in SSMS then you simply chose `Server name: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and Windows Authentication by default