# C# use program with local database on another computer without SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote simple program with local database created in Visual Studio. It works well on my computer, but when I run it on another computer (without any SQL Server) it says it can't find server and advise to check that local database runtime is turned on in SQL Server.

How do I make my application that uses LocalDb run on a client computer that doesn't have SQL Server installed?

Comment: Can't use the database if no database is installed. If you want something that you can release in a DLL (or embedded) form, look into SQLite.

Comment: You'll need to install the DB on that machine, or host one that the client can all access.

Comment: @Servy you mean i need install ms sql server express on client computer?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install the entire SQL Server Express on the client computer, you only need the `SqlLocalDB.msi`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately)

Comment: this file should be in folder with program?

Comment: No, you will install that on the client computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the database where the client can access it, like the current local machine or somewhere on their network. In any case you'll work, you'll need some kind of database.