# Connections to SQL Server database files (.mdf) require LocalDB or SQL Server Express to be installed and running on the local computer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 professional. When I tried to add Service-based Database to my project I got this error.

> Connections to SQL Server database files (.mdf) require LocalDB or SQL Server Express to be installed and running on the local computer. You may need to modify the setup and ensure Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools is selected and install the current version at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=125883

I also have Microsoft SQL Sever 2014 installed on my computer.
really need help.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Do you have *LocalDB* or *SQL Server Express* installed and running on the local computer? It doesn't mention *SQL Server 2014* at all.

Comment: No, I don't. But in Visual Studio 2010 I have a lot of local database which I don't have to externally install. So I think these might have the same feature as in VS2015. However how can I install  SQL Server Express or LocalDB on my VS 2015

Comment: Are you serious? There's a link **right in the error message you posted**.

Comment: @KenWhite I install SQL Server Express LocalDB and it works, Can you please post the answer so others people can solve the problem as mine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install localdb separately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately)

Comment: @soulivong Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. You need to have either LocalDB or SQL Server Express installed and running on the local computer, and you apparently don't.

Do as the error message instructs, go to the link provided in that error message, select Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, and install the latest version.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case it helps others, I recently received this error in Visual Studio. The error states to go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=125883. When going to this URL, it now redirects to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/. The new URL do not seems to have an obvious instructions on how to get Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. Here is what worked for me.

1. In Visual Studio, select **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates**
2. In the *Extensions and Updates pop-up box*, select **Installed** > **Updates**
3. Highlight *Microsoft SQL Server Update for database...* and click the **Update** button. If *Microsoft SQL Server Update for database...* is not listed, you can download SSDTSetup.exe from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.
4. Your default Web browser will prompt a download of SSDTSetup.exe
5. In your Downloads folder, **run SSDTSetup**
6. Follow the prompts of the installer

After doing this, just to play it safe, I restarted Visual Studio. This might not be necessary. I then did the following in Visual Studio.

1. In Visual Studio, if you do not already have a folder named App_Data, in the Solution Explorer panel, right-click the name of your site and select **Add** > **New Folder**. Name the new folder App_Data.
2. With the App_Data folder highlighted, press **Ctrl + Shift + A** (or right-click and select Add > New Item)
3. In the Add New Item pop-up box, select **Visual Basic or C#** > **Data** > **SQL Server Database**.  Click **Add**.

The error should not appear, and in Solution Explorer should now be a file named database1.mdf.

Comment: Very clear explanation and well instructions, though I can't not try because I have installed SQL Server Express, but this will surely help others.

Comment: @JeremyCanfield Man thank you so much for your help, your answer was very useful for me. Perfect

Comment: @Mauricio Sweet! I am glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 7):

Just do this. On Visual Studio, go to Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections. Here clear the "SQL Server Instance Name (blank for default)" option and write SQLEXPRESS