# LocalDb error after scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localdb

I just started with asp.net mvc, I used the scaffolding generator to create a controller.

My model is called: Person, I set up the DbContext class correctly.
It did generate all the views and the controller actions but it throws an exception and points me to:

```
    // GET: /Person/

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(db.Persons.ToList()); //this line is highlighted as error
    }
```

I browsed a few questions on SO and google and it basically says that I have to setup a localDB in order to get rid of that error.

If the resources are right, the localDb should be located at the App_Data folder right? Mine is empty ...

Isn't Visual Studio 2012 supposted to set that up for me ?

This is the error message:

```
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
```

Should I create the localDb file manually?

Any suggestions?

edit:

**This is my connectionString (Web.config)**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-PersonDb-20160108102518;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-PersonDb-20160108102518.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Install LocalDB - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately

Comment: @ramiramilu It's installed

Comment: then create MDF file manually.

Comment: @ramiramilu, create the file called: aspnet-PersonDb-20160108102518.mdf in the App_Data folder?

Comment: yes, if it is not there, then you have to create it.

Comment: @ramiramilu, nothing changed ... I created the files, same result

Comment: Can you see the DB in Visual Studio's Server Explorer? (*View* / *Server Explorer* / *Data Connections*)?

Comment: @ngm, I'll answer that question on monday when I'm back at work