# Asp.net updating database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

My project so far consists of a simple, and empty, asp.net project solution using nothing besides what visual studio provides when you start a new project.

For the first time I am using migrations to help in my development. So far I have enable migrations fine and added an initial migration via the package manager console. The only change I have done is modifying my Web.config to look at a new data source like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SYS-VIS-15\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GiggHub-20160704033906.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GiggHub-20160704033906;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now, when I go to update my database by running 'update-database' in the package manager console I get the following error:

> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Admin\Source\Workspaces\GigHub\GiggHub\GiggHub\App_Data\aspnet-GiggHub-20160704033906.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I've checked all my permissions that I'm aware of, but can't see what I need to tick or untick to overcome this error. Does anyone know what to do?

The full file output is all follows:

```
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\Admin\Source\Workspaces\GigHub\GiggHub\GiggHub\App_Data\aspnet-GiggHub-20160704033906.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<CreateDatabaseFromScript>b__19(DbConnection conn)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:9b2f396d-dadf-4d0b-a334-1197e86beed1
Error Number:5133,State:1,Class:16
```

Comment: Can you connect to your database using management studio ?

Comment: Provide some code to analyze, so that we can answer ur question.

Comment: You say you only have SSMS installed, does that mean that you don't have the database engine installed? Also when you say `or on the database` do you mean the entity model in EF designer?

Comment: I'm following this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/full-stack-dot-net-developer-fundamentals/table-of-contents with SSMS I can connect to my database fine, but I've not created any databases inside of it myself.

Comment: You said when you try to update the database you are getting an error, you have created database and tables in SSMS OR within VS only????

Comment: @NiravMadariya I've not written any code. All I've done so far is new project with MVC set up -> package management console 'enable-migrations' -> package management console -> 'add-migration InitialModel' -> PMC 'update-database' 

it's the last part where I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio as an administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio click on VIEW -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Expand **SQL Server** node.If you don't see (localdb) in that list it means you don't have it installed.

To install local db have a look at  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately) SO question