# SQL Server 2016 Developer version can not connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have reinstalled my SQL Server 2016 as for an unknown reason which lead to the SQL Server down...But, when I finished the installation, I found I can not connect to `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` any more. I got this error message from SQL Server.

> Cannot connect to (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

[image]

Anyone who have any ideas of how to solve this problem? I do need to speed up for my development, but the DB issue stops me to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LocalDB` is a special version of SQL Server **Express** - if you haven't installed it, you cannot use that server/instance name to connect to it.

You can easily install SQL Server Express LocalDB separately, side-by-side with SQL Server Developer edition - but you need to install it explicitly.

See [this other SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately) for more details

Comment: Cool! Thank you! Indeed, I was using Developer version, but it does not support to connect to MSSQLLocalDB. I have downloaded Express one, which is working very well now.

Comment: Hi Marc_s, sorry I forgot to accept your answer, I was too busy. Thank you  again!