# connection string works fine on windows 10 but not on windows 7

Tags: c#, connection-string

I've developed a wpf app with connection string to sql server 2014 database database works fine with windows 10 with sql server 2016 and but doesn't work  with windows 7 with sql server 2014!

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=LearningSystem;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|Parking.mdf;integrated security=True;Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install localdb separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320013/how-to-install-localdb-separately)

Comment: Please tell us what error messages you're getting so we aren't guessing what the issue might be.  "It doesn't work" is not useful information.

Comment: On windows 7 with sql server 2014 throws an exception massage: "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `localdb` created on your Windows 10 machine. You have to either copy database on `Windows 7` machine or create another one there.

> Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb
>
> attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|Parking.mdf

Comment: I've copied the database file. It exists in application's bin folder

Comment: You have to explicitly set `|DataDirectory|` using `CurrentDomain.SetData` or you can provide full path to test if your app is able to find db. Like `attachdbfilename=c:\projectname/bin/Parking.mdf`, replace path with your actual db path

Comment: LocalDB is a separate application; it has to be on the Win7 machine or he has to install it when he installs the WPF app. You should also never open with Write access a file in your Program Files folder; if he needs Write access he needs to copy the DB file to a place he has such access.